# Determine positive integer $k$ so that there are exactly 8 integer $n$ that $\frac{n^2+n+k+1}{3n+2}$ is an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Determine positive integer $k$ so that there are exactly 8 integer $n$ that $\frac{n^2+n+k+1}{3n+2}$ is an integer.

Comment: $\frac{n^2+n+k+1}{3n+2}$? Or something else? Please state clearly.

Comment: Yes, 3n+2 need to be inside a bracket

Answer (score 3):

Note that
 $$3n+2|n^2+n+k+1$$ iff $$3n+2|3n^2+3n+3k+3$$ iff $$3n+2|n+3k+3$$ iff $$3n+2|3n+9k+9$$ iff $$3n+2|9k+7.$$
So, you are looking for $k$ such that $9k+7$ has exactly $8$ divisors congruent to $2\mod 3$.

I think there are infinitely many such $k$'s satisfying this property.

For instance, let $p$ prime and $p\equiv 2\mod 3$.  Then $p^{16}$  has exactly $8$ divisors congruent to $2\mod 3$, namely $p,p^3,p^5,\dots,p^{15}$. So, if we choose $p$ such that $p^{16}$ has the form $9k+7$, we find one $k$ satisfying the condition. One example is $p=2$, so $k=(2^{16}-7)/9=7281$.

**Edit:** So, in the above I found a $k$ such that  there are exactly $8$ **natural numbers** $n$ such that $\frac{n^2+n+k+1}{3n+2}$ is an integer.

To solve the original problem of finding  a $k$ such that  there are exactly $8$ **integer numbers** $n$ such that $\frac{n^2+n+k+1}{3n+2}$ is an integer, we need to find $k$ such that $9k+7$ has exactly $8$ *positive or negative divisors* congruent to $ 2\mod 3$.

In that case, we can consider $p\equiv 1\mod 3$, now $p^7$ has exactly $8$ positive or negative divisors congruent to $ 2\mod 3$, namely $-1,-p,-p^2,\dots,-p^7$. So, if $p^7$ is of the form $9k+7$, we will find our $k$. One example is $p=7$, so $k=(7^7-7)/9=91504$.

Comment: Good approach. But n could be a negative number, for example n = -1

Comment: Oh, good point, but I think with some modifications should work.I'll try.

Comment: 1908 answer is wrong. It only brings 4 exactly n integrrs

Comment: which 1908? I said k=91504.

Comment: k = 7 is another answer. https://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2019/2019HypatiaSolution.pdf